# Using Python In IB TWS I am trying to get real time data saved to a file, but the file is empty, but the data can be seen in the console

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, tws

I am using the latest version of IB's TWS API and I want to write real-time data(not historical) to a file as it becomes available. My problem is that although I get no error messages, the file is always empty after multiple times the data has arrived. I tried putting it here: (inside the def **init** for class TestAPP

```
class TestApp(TestWrapper, TestClient):
def __init__(self):
    TestWrapper.__init__(self)
    TestClient.__init__(self, wrapper=self)
    # ! [socket_init]
    self.nKeybInt = 0
    self.started = False
    self.nextValidOrderId = None
    self.permId2ord = {}
    self.reqId2nErr = collections.defaultdict(int)
    self.globalCancelOnly = False
    self.simplePlaceOid = None
    self.f = open('c:\\histdata\\myfile.txt', 'w')
```

and the write statement inside

```
 def tickPrice(self, reqId: TickerId, tickType: TickType, price: float,
              attrib: TickAttrib):
    super().tickPrice(reqId, tickType, price, attrib)
    print("TickPrice. TickerId:", reqId, "tickType:", tickType,
          "Price:", price, "CanAutoExecute:", attrib.canAutoExecute,
          "PastLimit:", attrib.pastLimit, end=' ')
    print(str(reqId)+" "+str(price)+'\n')
    self.f.write(str(reqId)+" "+str(price)+'\n');
```

The main portion program where the reqMktdata are placed looks like

```
 try:
    app = TestApp()
    if args.global_cancel:
        app.globalCancelOnly = True
    # ! [connect]
    app.connect("127.0.0.1", args.port, clientId=0)
    # ! [connect]
    print("serverVersion:%s connectionTime:%s" % (app.serverVersion(),
                                                  app.twsConnectionTime()))
    time.sleep(4)
    file1 = open('c:\\histdata\\InputSymbols.txt', 'r')
    count = 0
    contract = Contract()
    while True:
        count += 1

        # Get next line from file
        line = file1.readline()
        if not line:
            break
        splitline = line.split(',')
   
        contract.symbol =splitline[1].strip('\n')
        contract.secType = "STK"
        contract.exchange = "SMART"
        contract.currency = "USD"
        contract.primaryExchange="NASDAQ"
        app.reqMktData(1000+count,contract,"233,236",False,False,[])
        time.sleep(1);
    file1.close()
    
    print("hi")
    # ! [clientrun]
    app.run()
    # ! [clientrun]
    
except:
    raise
finally:
    app.dumpTestCoverageSituation()
    app.dumpReqAnsErrSituation()
```

The input data file InputSymbols.txt looks like

```
STK,AAPL
STK,NFLX
STK,FB
```

The output myfile.txt is empty which is the problem
Sample output looks like (abbreviated)

```
TickPrice. TickerId: 1003 tickType: 7 Price: 357.11 CanAutoExecute: False PastLimit: False 1003 257.11
```

Thanks in advance for all looked at my problem!.

Comment: You never close the file.

Comment: What you say is not completly true. Python automatically closes open files before as the program exits. Ref: https://askinglot.com/does-python-close-files-automaticallyBut to make sure, I added the following code and it still did not work.:...(have trouble editing sorry.)   if (self.f.closed):
            a=1
        else:
            print(str(reqId)+" "+str(price)+'\n')
            self.f.write(str(reqId)+" "+str(price)+'\n');
            self.f.close

Comment: The program has no exit, you probably kill it somehow.  Figure out how you want the program to exit then close the file at that point.

Comment: I found the section of code when the user hits control=c to stop the program and added a self.f.close. Problem is still the same. I would really like to get some feedback from someone else who has good experience with TWS Python.  Thanks for Trying brian.

Comment: Test it by adding `self.f.close() self.disconnect()` after `self.f.write(..`   You will only get one line but you will see the problem.  If you modify the source code you may have to re-install the ibapi for the change to take effect.  BTW, I tested your program parts and added my own close logic and it worked fine.  If you post a minimal simple working example I will fix it for you.